# reference my own class in a pom file

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using "spring MVC" to build something(**project “A”**). I use maven to get the jar I need.

But I have a question, if I have a Java file(**a separate file**), a class in it, how can I use it in **project “A”** just like the other in pom.xml?

maybe it like this： when i use JSONObject i must edit pom.xml like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib<groupId>
        .........
    </dependency>
```

I mean i want my java file like JSONObject,i put it in pom file when it want use it in some project:

test.java:

```
class bc {
    public String test() {
        return "bc->test";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>test<groupId>
    .........
</dependency>
```

controller file (in springMVC)

```
import ...

@controller
@requestMapping(value="/api")
public class apiController {
    @RequestMapping.....................
    public @ResponseBody String testMyMavenClass() {
        return new bc().test()
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a class in the same project, just import it.  Is this a class you've created in the same project, or is this from a different project?

Comment: First get yourself more understanding on what Maven is doing. Understand what is a JAR.  There is obviously a lot of incorrectness on your understanding.  Maven does not reference a "class" etc.  If you are having your class in a separate project, what you need to do is: 1. create it as a JAR artifact using Maven, and install it in your local repository. 2. Refer that JAR artifact in your web app POM.  If it is simply a class in same project, you don't need to do anything.  Just use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure about how to use .class in maven pom file but Im sure you can define your own jar file. 
First, combine your classes into jar file.
Then, Define it inside pom.xml as external library.
Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm 
One more note, you can add below line to make sure maven knows where is external repository:

```
      <repositories>  
          <repository>  
              <id>in-project</id>  
              <name>In Project Repo</name>  
              <url>file:/${project.basedir}/libs</url>  
          </repository>  
      </repositories>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps me, but maybe I also need to understand, digest the following！ Thank you very much

Comment: `but maybe I also need to understand` what you need to undestand, guy? Easiest wayt to describe maven is tool to manage library dependencies. For example, without maven, you must place all your library in some where (local directory), then define them in classpath file. Maven will do it for you. You just need to define what you want to use. Almost library is provided by shared repository, but in shared repository does not include your library, so you must define it in local

Comment: Haha! 
I think maybe the language difference, my English is not good, I just literally translated my sentence! 
I mean i need to practice it and learn it! 
And thank you very much for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**: Install jar file to local maven repository:

- Export your project to jar file, then
- http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

**Method 2**: Use a repository manager. This is more advanced and requires some server skills. I can give you the name & link only, and you should do your research your self: https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype